# joint probability of correlated normal random variables

Tags: statistical-inference

Let $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ follow $ N(\delta, \alpha)$ and covariance between them is $\beta$. How to calculate $P(Z_1>0, Z_2>0)?$

Comment: Your subject line says "bivariate normal" but your posted question says "Let $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ follow $ N(\delta, \alpha)$ and covariance between them is $\beta$." To say "Let $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ follow $ N(\delta, \alpha)$ and covariance between them is $\beta$." does not imply that the pair $(Z_1,Z_2)$ has a bivariate normal distribution. It wouldn't be a bad idea to say that explicitly in the question.

Comment: Sure you are not in fact interested in the case $\delta=0$?

Comment: And the lack of context is chilling, especially in view of the fact that you seem to be asking again and again variants of the same question about joint normal distributions, to which the answer is always "No explicit formula in general". Sorry but I do not know where all this is going...

Answer (score 1):

The correlation between $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ will be $\beta /(\sigma_1\sigma_2) = \beta/\alpha^2$. Then the probability density function is
$$
f(z_1,z_2) = \frac1{2\pi\alpha^2\sqrt{1-\beta/\alpha^2}}
e^{-\frac1{2(1-\beta/\alpha^2)}}\left( \frac{(z_1-\delta)^2+(z_2-\delta)^2-2\beta/\alpha^2(z_1-\delta)(z2-\delta)}{\alpha^2}\right)
$$
The probability wanted is then
$$
\int_{z_1=0}^\infty \int_{z_2=0}^\infty f(z_1,z_2) dz_2\,dz_1
$$
Now for fixed $z_1$ the $z_2$ integral will give an erf result (in fact, it would even if the covariance were zero, because of the non-zero $\delta$) so 
the answer yo seek is an integral of an erf. Although this is quite tractable numerically, I know of no familiar function that represents it in closed form.

Comment: Thanks. So it is clear that we will not have an explicit form. If $\alpha = \frac{1+\gamma}{\gamma(1-\gamma)}$ and $\beta = 1/\gamma$ for $0<\gamma<1$. My main interest was to know, for what value of $\gamma$, $P(Z_1>0, Z_2>0)$ maximized?. I did simulations and it looks that it is true for $\gamma = 1/2$. I am trying to prove it using Slepian's inequality which is based on stochastic ordering. Please, any further thoughts..